# Retrofit OOM on large body

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm sending rather large files using retrofit, and I get occasional OOMs. The method:

```
@POST("/psm-service/model/{model}/video")
void sendVideo(@Header("X-Facebook-Access-Token") String token,
               @Header("X-FB-Id") long fbId,
               @Header("Content-Disposition") String contentDisposition,
               @Path("model") long modelId,
               @Body TypedOutput video,
               Callback<Response> callback);
```

And the service:

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setClient(new OkClient(Certification.getClient(this)))
            .setEndpoint(Api.ENDPOINT)
            .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
            .build();
    service = adapter.create(Api.ApiService.class);
```

The client is an OkHttpClient with custom SSL. My body is a TypedOutput that uses an android content URI and sets length, mimetype and filename.

```
@Override
public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    Utils.copyStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), out);
}

public static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
        throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Adjust if you want
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this should send my 50-something MB file in chunks of 1KB. Due to server limitations, I must pass the filesize. I've tried turning logging completely off, but that didn't help.

The OOM is thrown inside this method during one of the larger files.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 120252388 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 81MB until OOM
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
        at com.splunk.mint.network.io.OutputStreamMonitor.updateBody(OutputStreamMonitor.java:67)
        at com.splunk.mint.network.io.OutputStreamMonitor.write(OutputStreamMonitor.java:58)
        at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
        at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:133)
        at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:45)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink.write(HttpConnection.java:300)
        at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:133)
        at okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:148)
        at lt.segfoltas.common.util.Utils.copyStream(Utils.java:51)
        at lt.segfoltas.psm_casting.net.FormUploaderService$TypedStream.writeTo(FormUploaderService.java:565)
        at retrofit.client.OkClient$1.writeTo(OkClient.java:88)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:237)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:84)
        at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Edit:

I was suspicious about the bugsense methods in my stacktrace, so I commented out `Mint.initAndStartSession` and now my heap stays at an even 48MB, while it was going towards 200MB before. While this solves my problem, I'd like to keep using bugsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Splunk Mint has [issues](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintAndroidSDK/latest/DevGuide/Disablenetworkmonitoring) with OkHttp. Disabling network monitoring fixes the issue.